# Find a and b such that the system has (a) no solution; (b) many solutions; (c) a single solution

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

So, I have this system with three equations:

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x + 2y + z = 3\\
ay + 5z = 10\\
2x + 7y +az = b\end{array}\right.$$

And I am asked to find $a$ and $b$ such that the system has

1. no solution;
2. many solutions;
3. a single solution.

I have tried to reduce the system matrix but the augmented matrix has as second row $[0\ \  a\ \  5\ \  10]$ and I am not sure what to do with that $a$. Since nothing says that $a$ can not be zero, it is illegal to multiply the first line by $-a$ then sum the resulting line to the second line, right?

Any tips on how I can manage to proceed with this problem?

Comment: In general you would need to split into cases according to whether the candidate pivot element is zero or not. This can get unwieldy for large systems, but is generally the only _systematic_ procedure unless you're lucky enough to spot a way to sidestep it, such as the rearrangement José Carlos Santos describes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the system matrix$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&1&3\\0&a&5&10\\2&7&a&b\end{bmatrix}.$$If you multiply the first line by $-2$ and add it to the third one, you'll get$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&1&3\\0&a&5&10\\0&3&a-2&b-6\end{bmatrix}.$$Now, you can exchange the second and the third lines:$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&1&3\\0&3&a-2&b-6\\0&a&5&10\end{bmatrix}$$and then divide the second line by $3$:$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&1&3\\0&1&\frac{a-2}3&\frac{b-6}3\\0&a&5&10\end{bmatrix}.$$And now you can multiply the second line by $-a$ and add it to the third one:$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&1&3\\0&1&\frac{a-2}3&\frac{b-6}3\\0&0&5-\frac{a^2-2a}3&10-\frac{ab-6a}3\end{bmatrix}.$$Now, consider two cases: when $5-\frac{a^2-2a}3=0$ (that is, when $a=-3$ or $a=5$) and when $5-\frac{a^2-2a}3\ne0$. Can you take it from here?